# Magento Event Handling

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

For some reason, I can't get the **getEvent()** or **getRequest()** to work in my observer.

```
<!--Create an event-->
<events>
    <controller_action_predispatch>
        <observers>
            <example_observer>
                <class>example/observer</class>
                <method>controllerActionPredispatch</method>
            </example_observer>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_predispatch>
</events>
```

And here is the observer:

```
class MasteringMagento_Example_Model_Observer
{
    public function controllerActionPredispatch($observer){
        //die("testing"); //this runs fine
        $controllerAction = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();

        Mage::log($controllerAction->getRequest()->getParams());
    }
}
```

The `die("testing")` fires fine, but I can't get the rest of the observer code to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is correct. I guess logging is not enabled in **Admin - System - Config - Developer - Debug**

You can force logging with setting 4th parameter in `Mage::log()` to `true`.

Example:

```
$controllerAction = $observer->getControllerAction();
Mage::log($controllerAction->getRequest()->getParams(), null, 'my.log', true);
```

---

*Just to note ... you can also write `$controllerAction = $observer->getControllerAction();` (without `getEvent`)*

Comment: Thanks. Still not working. For some reason this is what it logs (an empty array):        2017-06-13T10:15:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
)

Comment: This is OK if your URL doesn't contain parameters ... try `domain.com?param=1` and check the logs.

Comment: Thanks. I will play around with it and let you know. At least it is logging something

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in config:

```
    <!--Create an event-->
<events>
    <controller_action_predispatch>
        <observers>
            <example_observer>
                <class>MasteringMagento_Example_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>controllerActionPredispatch</method>
            </example_observer>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_predispatch>
</events>
```

And use the log in observer as shown below:

```
class MasteringMagento_Example_Model_Observer
{
 public function controllerActionPredispatch($observer){
  //die("testing"); //this runs fine
  $controllerAction = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();

  Mage::log($controllerAction->getRequest()->getParams());
  Mage::log($controllerAction->getRequest()->getParams(), null, 'your.log', true);
  }
}
```

Comment: As he writes ... `die()` works, so the observer is correctly called. :)

Comment: yes. I have overlooked.